# How to detect players on a specific block in Minecraft 1.12.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am currently making a trolly Minecraft parkour map. I have two blocks, one on each side, so the players can jump to either side. I want to make it so when they jump on either of these blocks, the block is filled with air and they fall to their death. :) However, I cant figure out how to use the /detect command. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`/detect` is not a command on it's own. it's a subcommand of `execute`.

I think what you want is as simple as

```
/execute @a[..] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ <block> <blockstate> /setblock ~ ~-1 ~ air
```

replace the `<block>` with the block you're trying to detect and the `<blockstate>` with the respective blockstate (or a `*` for "doesn't matter which blockstate").

e.g.:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ stone * /setblock ~ ~-1 ~ air
```

this command will replace any stone block any player is trying to stand on with air.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the help. I did not know that it had to be used with /execute. Thanks!